# cordova 11.0.0 and Ajax request not working (readyState=0)

Tags: ajax, cordova

I need to migrate my Cordova application for ANDROID to version 11.0.0 (to have Android API version 32)
Previously I was on Cordova 9.0.0 (everything worked fine)

In version Cordova 9.0.0 I added the plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist to manage permissions, but since version 10 Cordova whitelist is integrated into Cordova

This small application makes an ajax call (via Jquery v3.4.1), to a secure domain (ex: https://www.example.com/mypgm.php)
but it does not work anymore I have the error code readyState=0 (The connection did not start)

Here are my settings that allow me to allow a javascript call to a third-party domain:
- config.xml
`<access origin="*" />`
- index.hml (which contains javascript script that calls AJAX function
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />`

In my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

thank you in advance for your help

I want my Ajax call to work

Comment: Additional information: this application is intended for the ANDROID platform

Comment: I solved my problem

In config.xml you must add the following line (for Android):
<preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />

Here is the source: https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1354